# Installing OpenFoam on Mac OS

Tags: macos, openfoam

Can anyone give instructions that work? There have been various posts on this but nothing that works for me. My attempt below is the best I can do.

Trying to install OpenFoam v1606+ on OS X El Capitan.

1. I downloaded Docker and successfully ran their toy example.
2. The OpenFoam instructions say 
   *After installing, open the Launchpad and locate the ‘Docker Quickstart Terminal’ icon* 
   There is no such icon. There is a Docker icon which I click, and it confirms that Docker is running.
   *Click the icon to launch a Docker Quickstart Terminal window.*
   Cannot find such a terminal, so I guess that a standard Mac terminal shell will do.
3. *Make sure the Docker daemon is running:  “docker info”* 
   I get :
   *Containers: 3
   Running: 0
   Paused: 0
   Stopped: 3
   Images: 2
   Server Version: 1.12.1
   …*
   Is this correct?
4. *Download the following scripts from the release instructions and put them in a local directory (e.g. home directory)
   installMacOpenFOAM+
   startMacOpenFOAM+”*
   I downloaded both.
5. *Download and create the Docker container  …
   docker-machine ssh default $HOME/installMacOpenFOAM+ $HOME*
   I get
   *Host does not exist: “default"*
6. So instead I ran installMacOpenFOAM+ directly. (Forgot to chmod initially)
   *chmod a+x installMacOpenFOAM+
   ./installMacOpenFOAM+*
   I get a download of the required file, but then
   *docker: Error response from daemon: Mounts denied: 
   The path /etc/sudoers.d
   is not shared from OS X and is not known to Docker.
   You can configure shared paths from Docker -> Preferences... -> File Sharing.
   See https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/osxfs/#namespaces for more info.*
   There is no file or directory /etc/suders.d . Tried adding /etc via Docker->Preferences but this did not work.

Not enough room to complete this saga.

Comment: This has been solved very recently using Docker: https://twitter.com/CFDdirect/status/821692602172981248 I really advice using this workflow as it really speed-up development time for me.

Comment: Please check
https://www.scibyte.cn/products/openfoam-macos/index_en.html

Answer (score 0):

OpenFOAM v2112 works out of the box (tested on Mac OS 12.1).

Use command line tools and brew to install dependencies.

```
brew install boost
brew install cgal
brew install open-mpi
brew install metis
brew install scotch
```

Create a case sensitive volume

```
diskutil ap addVolume disk1 'Case-sensitive APFS' OpenFOAM -role D
```

Make a symbolic link to the new volume

```
ln -s /Volumes/OpenFOAM $HOME/OpenFOAM
```

Download the OpenFOAM sources in the new case sensitive volume

```
cd /Volumes/OpenFOAM
curl -L   https://dl.openfoam.com/source/v2112/OpenFOAM-v2112.tgz > OpenFOAM-v2112.tgz
tar xzf OpenFOAM-v2112.tgz
```

Combine preferences in ~/.OpenFOAM/prefs.sh

```
mkdir -p $HOME/.OpenFOAM
echo 'WM_COMPILER=Clang' >   $HOME/.OpenFOAM/prefs.sh
echo 'WM_COMPILE_OPTION=Opt' >>    $HOME/.OpenFOAM/prefs.sh
echo 'WM_MPLIB=SYSTEMOPENMPI' >>  $HOME/.OpenFOAM/prefs.sh
echo 'export WM_NCOMPPROCS=$(sysctl -n hw.ncpu)' >> $HOME/.OpenFOAM/prefs.sh
echo 'WM_LABEL_SIZE=32' >> $HOME/.OpenFOAM/prefs.sh
```

Source the settings and install OpenFOAM

```
source etc/bashrc
./Allwmake > log.Allwmake 2>&1
```

For additional info: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/357395955_OpenFOAM_installation_on_Mac?utm_source=twitter&rgutm_meta1=eHNsLS9NZktnbTVhZ0cxbmpONUgrNzd1dlgxem5abHNvTHd1bVI3RlhhMk9aYUk3aXNkNC9ERVdIeFBGY3VLZ3g0WkU2N1F4WHRuTjlnTE92YTVERzlqaG83TT0%3D

Comment: Can other versions of OpenFOAM be installed in the same way?
Does this method have the same spirit as the way in this link?
https://www.scibyte.cn/products/openfoam-macos/index_en.html

Comment: The idea here is to build the OpenFOAM from sources directly on Mac OS.